# PHP CURL Storing cookies after request

Tags: php, curl, cookies

```
function login($username, $password) {
        $curl = curl_init("http://loginapi.com");
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=".$user."&password=".$password;
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
        $header = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        if(preg_match('errormessagelink\?msg\=(.*?)\n/', $header)){
        return false;  // error exists
        } else {
        return true; // error doesnt exist
        }
    }
```

I made a curl function that calls a login api and stores cookies, my question is how do I make it store cookies if an error message isn't displayed? I want the cookies being stored if the if statement at the end is true.

Comment: That's up to the website.  If they are throwing the error before passing any cookies, then you don't get any.

Comment: @Forbs the thing is, they pass the cookies even if the error message is displayed, is there no way for me to only make the script get the cookies if error message is not thrown?

Comment: Then I am confused, if they are passing cookies, it would be in your cookies.txt file.  However those 'cookies' might be related to the username and password combination.  Did you dump out the cookies.txt file?

Comment: @Forbs Here's what happens, when I call the curl function, with a username and password that aren't valid, it calls the API and makes a cookie file with an invalid PHPSESSID and it redirects to the page errorpage.com?msg=1 meaning the username/password isn't valid, my question is, if it's possible to store the cookies ONLY if the error message isn't thrown, like I already did an if statement indicating if the error msg is thrown or not, but can I also add a piece of code which stores the cookies from the API after it checks if the error message is thrown or not??

Comment: That sounds like the website is sending you that information as I said earlier.  They are probably trying to invalidate any cookie on the system to prevent hacking.